# Kohana 3.2 installation downloaded. Where is the views folder in the application folder?

Tags: kohana

Kohana 3.2 installation package was downloaded from the official website. Where is the views folder in the application folder as it's expected to be there? The only folder I see in the application folder is classess folder.

Comment: If you are new to kohana i suggest you to go through the documentation http://Kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana at least "Getting Started" and "Basic Usage" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Kohana** doesnt require you to use `APPPATH/views` folder. You can create views in your modules, for example. So, installation package contains not empty folders, like `classes/controller`. If you want to store views on `APPPATH/views` folder, just create it.